# regex nonconsecutive match

Tags: regex, dart

I'm trying to match a word that has 2 vowels in it (doesn't have to be consecutively) but the regex I've come up either matches nothing or not enough. This is the last iteration (dart).

```
  final vowelRegex = new RegExp(r'[aeiouy]{2}');
```

Here's an example sentence being parsed and it should match, one, shoulder, their, and over. It's only matching shoulder and their. I understand why, because that's the expression I defined. How can the expression be defined to match on 2 vowels, regardless of position in the word?

```
  one shoulder their the which over
```

The expression only needs to be tested on one word at a time so hopefully this simplifies things.

Comment: what happens when you use [aeiouy]{0,}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both of the previous two answers are incorrect.**

`(\S*[aeiouy]\S*){2}` can match substrings of non-whitespace characters *even if they contain non-word characters* ([proof](https://regex101.com/r/SqjN8T/5)).

`\S*[aeiouy]\S*[aeiouy]\S*` has the same problem ([proof](https://regex101.com/r/SqjN8T/6)).

---

**Correct solution:**

```
\b([^\Waeiou]*[aeiou]){2}\w*\b
```

And if you want only whitespace to count as the word boundary (rather than any non-word character), then use the following regex where the target word is in capture group `\2`.

```
(\s|^)(([^\Waeiou]*[aeiou]){2}\w*)(\s|$)
```

Comment: AFAIK the last example doesn't work in the browser (downvote wasn't me)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Actually... I may have misunderstood you.  What do you mean exactly when you say "in the browser"?

Comment: I mean JavaScript regex. http://regexr.com/3f093 Darts regex implementation is compatible with JS and doesn't support lookbehind

Comment: Since it only needs to match *at least* `two vowels, you can even use the simpler `\b(?:\w*?[aeiou]){2}\w*`

Comment: @lrn True.  However, I prefer to use negated classes rather than lazy evaluation whenever possible, since lazy evaluation is much less efficient performance-wise.

Comment: I don't see any difference in performance in this case (in Chrome), but it's true that in some cases, the failure case becomes more expensive because the `\w*?` and the following `[aeiou]` are not disjoint. If used improperly, it can cause blowup. As always, the performance characteristics of RegExps isn't easy to see.

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```dart
new RegExp(r'(\w*[aeiouy]\w*){2}');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
\S*[aeiouy]\S*[aeiouy]\S*
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/ZRuf4e/3)

1. `\S*` matches any non-whitespace character (equal to `[^\r\n\t\f ]`)
2. `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times
3. `[aeiou]` Match a single character present in the list below `[aeiou]`

For input string : `one shoulder their the which over`

it will match four word: `one shoulder their over`

Comment: The question was about words with 2 vowels.

Comment: it does that, doesn't it ?

Comment: `shoulder` has 3 vowels.

Comment: Op wrote : "Here's an example sentence being parsed and it should match, one, shoulder, their, and over." which means minimum two vowels

Comment: Perhaps it means minimum of two.

Comment: Maybe add the 'y' in the regex ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Maverick_Mrt, I upvoted your solution but went with a diff accepted answer because of the whitespace explanation. I appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 2):

I'd do:

```
\b(?:\w*[aeiouy]+\w*){2,}\b
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b            : word boundary
  (?:         : start non-capture group
    \w*       : 0 or more word characters
    [aeiouy]+ : 1 or more vowels 
    \w*       : 0 or more word characters
  ){2,}       : end group repeated at least twice
\b            : word boundary
```